# Unable To connect remote server (Web Service)

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, webservices-client

[image]

I have tried to integrate this web service into my asp.net project but it popups such type of error ! If you have any idea regarding this kindly give me solution. There are very rare materials about oodle web services  and oodle API.

Try this URL to have more idea about my problem
http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=chicago&category=vehicle/car

Answer (score 4):

That simply isn't a SOAP Web Service. It's a REST XML service. REST services do not provide self-describing meta data in the form of WSDL.

You need another way of communicating with the service. If there isn't a C# wrapper available, you will probably have to write the url generator yourself, and have the .NET Framework deserialize the xml documents for you into nicely written classes *(that you, also, write yourself)*.

Try reading more at: [Oddle Developer Center](http://developer.oodle.com/)

**EDIT:**
Also, if you are downloading the XML document from within a web application, there are a couple of things you need to consider.

When you are developing, make sure you are running Visual Studio as an **Administrator**.

When you deploy to your hosting provider, make sure you are not running **Medium Trust**, because that might stop you from accessing external web sources.

But still, I can't figure out why the **Add Web Reference** dialog can't connect to the oodle web server. Check your network settings, your firewall settings and so on. If you are able to visit the URL in your web browser, you should be able to download the document through code.

Comment: But how to get data from URL ? I mean totally new request and responses are generated ! So how can I map it ?

Comment: You can let WCF handle that for you. Here are a couple of pointers: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pedram/archive/2008/04/21/how-to-consume-rest-services-with-wcf.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx

Comment: ...or you do it all manually. Then you need some method(s) for generating the proper urls, then use a `WebClient` object to create a request and then open the response `Stream`. Then there are a few different ways of getting the data back in a structured way. `XmlDocument`, `XDocument` or `XmlSerializer` are starting points...

Comment: Have a look on my answer ! Still it is !

Answer (score 4):

```
try
    {
        string url = @"http://api.oodle.com/api/v2/listings?key=TEST&region=chicago";

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);

       }
  catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());

    }
```

This statement creates exception

```
   string result = webClient.DownloadString(url);
```

and exception details are

```
   System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected 
party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed 
because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.0.101:808 at 
System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress 
socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, 
Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, 
IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception 
stack trace --- at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& 
request) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address) at 
System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address) at _Default.lnkGoTo_Click(Object 
sender, EventArgs e) in d:\MyDemoz\oodleDemo\Default.aspx.cs:line 58
```

Comment: Read the error message. It tells you what is wrong. **A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond** Either the server times out or it refuses your connection for other reasons. Maybe there are only certain `User-Agent` values that are allowed... Are you able to visit the URL using your web browser? For me, it takes about 6 seconds to download the XML document using that URL. Does it take longer for you? Do you even get a result?

Comment: Oh, wait a minute... Is this a web app? Are you running Medium Trust? And again, are you running your Visual Studio instance as Administrator? Because when I run your code from within a Console App (using Console.WriteLine instead of Response.Write), it works perfectly. Try running VS as Admin! I updated my answer.

Comment: Let me run as Administrator !

Comment: Still Its not working !!! Let me try another way http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx

Comment: @atornblad Same error with new option !! Yaar I fed Up ! Let me try XML serialization !

Comment: XML Serialization won't help you here, because the error occurs before you even get anything back. There is a network error - not an XML serialization error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7199/discussion-between-no-one-and-atornblad)